# Integration of Mavlink and LabView

Tags: labview, mavlink

I'm using mavlink with a pixhawk flight controller. I want to send and receive packets of data to and from LabView to mavlink. How can I create a link between mavlink and LabView?

Comment: We need much more detail. Is the 'pixhawk flight controller' hardware or software or both? What are you able to do with this at the moment and what aspect of it do you want LabVIEW to do? I can see that [MAVLink](http://mavlink.io/en/) is a protocol with implementations available in various languages, so one simple option might be to write an interface layer in Python, say - but what are you trying to achieve and what skills do you have?

Answer (score 0):

MAVLink has a C-library so you should be able to call that from LabView using the [Call Library Function Node](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/glang/call_library_function/).